# Convergence of $\int |\frac{\sin x}{x}|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I know that $\int_1^{\infty}|\frac{\sin x}{x}|$ diverges.

But:

**(1).** the primitive function of $|\sin x|$ is bounded.

**(2).** $\frac{1}{x}$ converges to $0$.

**(claim).** So by applying Dirichlet's test the integral should converges.

I cant seem to put the finger on where is the fault in that argument claimed above?

Comment: Your argument would also fail for the simpler integral of $\frac1x$.  You may have misread [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: Why do you think the integral of $|\sin x|$ is bounded?

Comment: Because it is -cos x sgn(sin x) which is clearly bounded.

Comment: No, that's the derivative

Comment: If you put it in wolfram alpha then this is what comes out.

Answer (score 3):

The integral of $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$ isn't bounded. In particular, on each interval $[n \pi + \pi/4, n\pi + 3\pi/4]$, we have $\lvert \sin(x) \rvert > 1/2$. Thus
$$
\int_1^\infty \lvert \sin x \rvert \, dx > \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\pi}{4} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Maybe its a stupid question, but I didn't quite understand the argument that $|\sin (x)| > 1/2$ for $x \in [n\pi - \pi/2, n\pi + \pi/2] \forall n$. For example if I take $n = 1$, then $\pi\in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Vizag Oh, that's because I completely messed up my intervals. I didn't think too much about it --- I will edit and have it say in intervals $[(2n+1)(\pi/2) - \pi/4, (2n+1)(\pi/2) + \pi/4]$. The point is that there is a trivial periodic interval in which $\sin x$ is greater than $1/2$ in size.

Comment: any non-zero positive continuous periodic function has trivially an infinite integral on any set that contains infinitely many period intervals (since it has a non-zero positive integral on any period interval by continuity), in particular on any unbounded interval

Comment: Isnt the function -cos x sgn(sin x) bounded?

Comment: @math What does that question have to do with this post?

Comment: Because -cos x sgn(sin x) is the primitive function of abs(sin x) and is bounded.

Comment: @math if by primitive function you mean the function $\int_0^x \lvert \sin t \rvert dt$, then you're mistaken. One big clue is that your function can be negative. I'm not sure how you computed that, but you have apparently made a mistake.

Comment: By primitive function I mean the antiderivative. You can verifiy this by putting the command "integrate abs(sin x)" in wolfram alpha.